# How to set create a password generator and ask how long password should be?

Tags: python

So I want to write a Python code, which creates a random password for the user. It needs to ask the user how long they want their password to be, and have a minimum set of characters.

I have tried to search for something for many weeks and I just can't find it, so sorry if this has already been solved.

Here is the code I have so far, don't know what other piece of code I need and where I have to use in order to get what I want.

```
import random
import secrets
import string


# This variable includes numbers
digits = string.digits

# This variable includes uppercase and lowercase letters
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

# This variable includes symbols
symbols = "!#$%&'()*+, -./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"

password = ''.join(secrets.choice(digits + letters + symbols) for t in range(20))

def message():
    print("Hello, here is a password generator: ")
    print("Choose the length?")
    print(userGen())

def userGen():
    upper = int(input("How many letters you want? "))
    spec = int(input("How many symbols you want? "))
    num = int(input("How many numbers you want? "))
    return passGen(upper,spec,num)

def passGen(upper,spec,num):
    new_password = ""
    for i in range(upper):
        new_password += random.choice(letters)
    for x in range(spec):
        new_password += random.choice(symbols)
    for y in range(num):
        new_password += random.choice(digits)

    pass_word = list(new_password)
    shuff = random.shuffle(pass_word)
    new_pass = "".join(pass_word)
    password = secrets.token_urlsafe(7)
    return new_pass


message()
```

Comment: So then if they choose 3 letters, 2 symbols and 0 numbers, then what should the remaining 2 characters be to match your 7 character minimum? Should they be letters, symbols or numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your userGen() with this:

```
def userGen():
    c = 0
    upper = int(input("How many letters you want? "))
    spec = int(input("How many symbols you want? "))
    num = int(input("How many numbers you want? "))
    c += upper + num +spec
    if c < 7:
        print('Your password is too short.')
        userGen()
    else:
        return passGen(upper,spec,num)
```

Edit:

```
import random
import string
import secrets

length = 7


# This variable includes numbers
digits = "1234567890"

# This variable includes uppercase and lowercase letters
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

# This variable includes symbols
symbols = "!#$%&'()*+, -./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"

password = ''.join(secrets.choice(digits + letters + symbols) for t in range(20))
def message():
    print("Hello, here is a password generator. ")
    print("Choose the length of your characters:")
    passGen()

def passGen():
    c = 0
    upper = int(input("How many letters you want? "))
    spec = int(input("How many symbols you want? "))
    num = int(input("How many numbers you want? "))
    c += upper + num +spec
    if c < length:
        print('Your password is too short.')
        passGen()
    else:
        new_password = ""
        for i in range(upper):
            new_password += random.choice(letters)
        for x in range(spec):
            new_password += random.choice(symbols)
        for y in range(num):
            new_password += random.choice(digits)

        pass_word = list(new_password)
        shuff = random.shuffle(pass_word)
        new_pass = "".join(pass_word)
        password = secrets.token_urlsafe(7)
        print(new_pass)

message()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish can be done with a simple `if` statement ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) is a good resource).
You want to:

- check if the user input a combination that adds up to 7 characters
- if that is true:

  - assign the password like you are currently doing it
- if it isn't true, you have at least 2 options:

  - print an error message like @Ktoto suggested
  - force the password to be at least 7 characters by setting the numbers of letters, numbers and symbols yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements like this:

```
def userGen():
    upper = int(input("How many letters you want? "))
    spec = int(input("How many symbols you want? "))
    num = int(input("How many numbers you want? "))
    if int(upper) + int(spec) + int(num) <= 7:
        # your code
    return passGen(upper, spec, num)
```

Then add more chars to the certain type of chars you like.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear what sort of characters should be added if the user's choices do not add up to enough, so I suggest that you simply ask the user to try again until there are enough.

Although not strictly an answer to the question, here is a suggestion about some general tidying up of the code that you could do.  It includes the use of two dictionaries: `characters` which hold the types of characters, and `choices` which holds the user's choices about the number of each type of item.  If you wanted to change things, for example split 'letters' into separate counts for upper and lower case, then you would only need to change the dictionary at the top.

```
import random

characters = {'digits': '1234567890',
              'letters': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
              'symbols': "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"}


def getChoices(min_total=7):
    print('Hello, here is a password generator: ')
    print('Choose the length of your characters?')
    while True:
        total = 0
        choices = {}
        for category in characters.keys():
            number = int(input(f'How many {category} do you want? '))
            choices[f'num_{category}'] = number
            total += number
        if total >= min_total:
            return choices
        else:
            print(f'Need at least {min_total} characters - please try again')


def passGen(choices):
    new_password = ''
    for category, options in characters.items():
        for i in range(choices[f'num_{category}']):
            new_password += random.choice(options)
    pass_word = list(new_password)
    random.shuffle(pass_word)
    new_pass = ''.join(pass_word)
    return new_pass


def main():
    choices = getChoices()
    print(f'Your choices: {choices}')
    password = passGen(choices)
    print(f'Your password: {password}')


main()
```

Comment: Hey thank you, i see that this updated course works well. 

I have however updated the code and posted it in the comments with another method that somebody else here provided and it does not seem to work like i want whereas yours does. 

Do you know why? 

It's in another comment I post to my own answer. I just want to learn why. 

Because when i try running the program and choose a password with more than 7 characters it works.

But if i run the program and try less than 7 and then again with more than 7 it gives me "none" as a result.

Comment: @ErnesFernandez It appears that you are now asking about Ktoto's answer. Bear in mind that that may be edited soon, but it looks like they are trying to implement the "try again" by using a recursive call to the same function. That won't work, the way that they've coded it (although `return passGen()` instead of `passGen()` might do.) No, you really do want to use a loop here -- note the use of `while`. This is not a situation where recursion really helps -- once you've looked at some text-book examples of recursion you will get a feel for what sort of situations it can be genuinely useful.